# How to remove text in subscribe button embedded on website

Tags: css, youtube

How can I remove the text `YouTube` on my website's youtube subscribe button?  I tried to apply some styles to target the text but still displaying. I want to apply some style with the button. Please see the fiddle below:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jc47r8ys/2/

Answer (score 0):

The text "YouTube" is coming from the following CSS file:
https://www.youtube.com/yts/cssbin/www-subscribe-embed-webp-vflp1Z4Vh.css
(Open the link and you search for "YouTube")

I'm not sure, but you might be able to override it. (turns out you should not)

Comment: Can you add an example for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not only can you not remove the text, I would go so far as to say it may be a violation of YouTube’s policy to do so. You can not access the text using a script, as it falls under the [same origin policy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and they are smarter than to let you use simple CSS to accomplish this.

They do, however, allow you to [customize your button](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button) as per their pre-determined guidelines.

Sorry to disappoint, hope this helps.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you add a fiddle for this?

Comment: I have done some research and changed my answer. Unfortunately it seems you aren’t able to do this.